# when is it safe to swap the order of differentiation with integration?

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

Let $f(u)=\cos u$ and 
$$g(u)=1-u^2,-1\leq u \leq 1;g(u)=0, otherwise\tag{0}$$.
Thus
$$\partial_u^2g(u)=-2,-1\leq u \leq 1;\partial_u^2g(u)=0, otherwise\tag{1}$$.

Let $h(u)$ be the convolution of $f(u)$ and $g(u)$:
$$h(u):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u-x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x=4\cos u (\sin1-\cos1)\tag{2}$$.

So
$$h(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(u-x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x=4\cos u (\sin1-\cos1)\tag{3}$$.

From $h(u)=4\cos u (\sin1-\cos1)$, we have:
$$\partial_u^2h(u)=-4\cos u (\sin1-\cos1)\tag{4}$$.

From
$$\partial_u^2h(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\partial_u^2f(u-x)\mathrm{d}x\tag{5},$$
we obtain
$$\partial_u^2h(u)=\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)(-\cos(u-x))\mathrm{d}x=-4\cos u (\sin1-\cos1)\tag{6}$$.

From
$$\partial_u^2h(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\partial_u^2g(u-x)\mathrm{d}x\tag{7},$$
we obtain
$$\partial_u^2h(u)=\int_{u-1}^{u+1}\cos x(-2)\mathrm{d}x=-4\cos u (\sin1)\tag{8}$$.

***Question:***

The results for $\partial_u^2h(u)$ that we obtain from (4) and (6) are the same and seem to be correct. But result for $\partial_u^2h(u)$ that I obtain from (8) seems to be wrong.

What is the problem?

Thanks-
mike

***Update***
If we define $g(u)$ in terms of HeavisideTheta function as
$$g(u) := (1 - u^2) HeavisideTheta(1 - u) HeavisideTheta(1 + u)\tag{9}$$
Then we get the right result from (7):
$$\partial_u^2h(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\partial_u^2g(u-x)\mathrm{d}x=-4\cos u (\sin1-\cos1)\tag{8b}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your issue is that $g$ is not differentiable (and two-times differentiable) at $-1$ and $1$. 
What you are looking for is Leibniz integral rule.

If you have a function $f$ defined on $I$ such as $f(u) = \int_T g(u,x)dx$ with $g:I \times T \rightarrow J$. To swap the signs of the derivative and the integral, one of the prerequisite is for $F_u:x \rightarrow g(u,x)$ to have a derivative on $T$.

In $(6)$, the integration is actually between $-1$ and $1$, where your function is continuous and differentiable, so it gives the same result with $T = ]-1,1[$. However, in $(7)$, it becomes between $u-1$ and $u+1$, which depends on $u$; you cannot define a set interval $T$ and swap the integral and the derivative.

Or, more intuitively in this case, your region of integration depends on your variable, so you cannot swap them.